# Cannot convert value of type 'JSON' to expected argument type 'String?' SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, alamofire

I'm trying to parse json using AlamoFire but I'm getting an error and I can't figure it out. Below is my content view and class. I'm getting the error inside of the for loop.

```
import SwiftUI
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON


struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var obs = Observer()
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("testing")
        
    }
    
    
    
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


class Observer: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var datas = [UsersModel]()
    
    init() {
        AF.request("http://www.ohwn.life/test.json").responseData { (data) in
            let json = try! JSON(data: data.data!)
            
            for i in json {
                print(i.1)
                self.datas.append(UsersModel(id: i.1["id"], first_name: i.1["first_name"], last_name: i.1["last_name"], user_name: i.1["user_name"], email: i.1["email"], password: i.1["password"], address: i.1["address"], state: i.1["state"], city: i.1["city"], zipcode: i.1["zipcode"], birth_date: i.1["birth_date"], created_at: i.1["create_at"], updated_at: i.1["updated_at"], country_id: i.1["country_id"], is_auto: i.1["is_auto"]))
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my model

```
struct UsersModel: Codable {
    let id, first_name, last_name, user_name: String?
    let email: String?
    let password: String?
    let address, state, city, zipcode: String?
    let birth_date: String?
    let created_at, updated_at, country_id: String?
    let is_auto: String?
}
```

been working on this for a while. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you want to use SwiftyJSON or Codable? Also, which line is getting the compiler error message?

Comment: I want to use Codable. I'm getting the error here on line 58

self.datas.append(UsersModel(id: i.1["id"], first_name: i.1["first_name"], last_name: i.1["last_name"], user_name: i.1["user_name"], email: i.1["email"], password: i.1["password"], address: i.1["address"], state: i.1["state"], city: i.1["city"], zipcode: i.1["zipcode"], birth_date: i.1["birth_date"], created_at: i.1["create_at"], updated_at: i.1["updated_at"], country_id: i.1["country_id"], is_auto: i.1["is_auto"]))

Comment: Well if you want to use Codable don't use SwiftJSON. It makes no sense. Codable means JSONDecoder... Then there would be no "append", you would just have the data decoded, kaboom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `responseDecodable` to parse responses into any `Decodable` type. For instance, to parse an array of your `UsersModel` type:

```swift
AF.request("http://www.ohwn.life/test.json").responseDecodable(of: [UsersModel].self) { response in
// Do something with the response.
}
```